# Add enclosing tag for only UnOrdered list from Rich Text Editor in UL

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I need to style UL's coming from Rich Text Editor in Sitecore. I am trying to find out if there is a class that I can add to all UL's coming from Sitecore's Rich Text Editor.

Thanks in Advance
Ashok

Comment: All UL's from all RTE fields or just some UL's from some RTE fields?

Comment: All UL's from all RTE fields

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is just to wrap your `FieldRenderer` with an HTML element with appropriate class applied in code:

```
<div class="rich-text">
    <sc:FieldRenderer ID="frRichTextField" runat="server" FieldName="MyFieldName" />
</div>
```

And then add in some CSS styles to handle your UL's within this:

```
.rich-text ul {
    /* add in your styling */
}
```

You can also use the `before` and `after` properties of the FieldRenderer to pass in your tag:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer ID="frRichTextField" runat="server" FieldName="MyFieldName" 
    Before="<div class='rich-text'>" After="</div>" />
```

**EDIT:**

If you wanted to be more drastic then you could add in your own `renderField` pipeline processor to [ensure your control is always wrapped with the required tag](http://www.mikkelhm.dk/post/2013/12/18/Ensuring-that-p-tag.aspx) or you could make use of the [enclosingTag property](http://nttdatasitecore.com/Blog/2013/October/Using-EnclosingTag-in-Page-Editor) and patch the `AddBeforeAndAfterValues` pipeline instead:

```
namespace MyCustom.Pipelines.RenderField
{
    public class AddBeforeAndAfterValues
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
            if (args.Before.Length > 0)
                args.Result.FirstPart = args.Before + args.Result.FirstPart;
            if (args.After.Length > 0)
            {
                RenderFieldResult result = args.Result;
                string str = result.LastPart + args.After;
                result.LastPart = str;
            }
            if (args.EnclosingTag.Length == 0 || args.Result.FirstPart.Length <= 0 && args.Result.LastPart.Length <= 0)
                return;

            // check if a css class paramter has been passed in
            string cssClass = args.Parameters.ContainsKey("class") ? args.Parameters["class"] : String.Empty;
            // add the class to the enclosing tag property
            args.Result.FirstPart = StringExtensions.FormatWith("<{0} class='{1}'>{2}", (object)args.EnclosingTag, cssClass, (object)args.Result.FirstPart);
            args.Result.LastPart = StringExtensions.FormatWith("{0}</{1}>", (object)args.Result.LastPart, (object)args.EnclosingTag);
        }
    }
}
```

Patch the Sitecore config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
               xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <renderField>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel"
                   set:type="MyCustom.Pipelines.RenderField.AddBeforeAndAfterValues, MyCustom.Pipelines" />
      </renderField>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And then call the `FieldRenderer` with the EnclosingTag set and pass in your class parameter:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer ID="frRichTextField" runat="server" FieldName="MyFieldName" 
    EnclosingTag="div" Parameters="class=rich-text" />
```

This really doesn't add much over using the `before`/`after` properties though and I would generally try to stay away from overwriting default Sitecore processors to save heartache when upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You could either tap into relevant pipelines or update your sublayouts so that you always have a fixed class around every instance of the rich text field rendering:

```
<div class="rtf">
    <sc:Text ID="scContent" runat="server" FieldName="Content" />
</div>
```

You will have to make sure as a developer that all current and future instances of rich text field renderings are enclosed by a tag with this class.
You could then include in the global CSS, a common style for this class.

```
.rtf ul {
    ...
    ....
}
```

If you don't want to have to add this wrapper for every single rtf rendering, you could tap into a relevant pipeline. (Note - this might be a better approach with regard to code maintainability)

You could choose to use one of the two:

- **renderField** pipeline 
  or the
- **saveRichTextContent** pipeline

So you would add a new processor for either of these pipelines, in which you could access the text within rich text fields only and process that as you please (easier to manipulate the html using the html agility pack)

If you use ***renderField*** pipeline - the text within the rich text field in sitecore will not change, the code you write will execure only while rendering the field - in preview / page editor or normal mode.

Using ***saveRichTextContent*** pipeline on the other hand, will update the in the rich text field when the content author clicks on save (after entering the text) in content editor mode.

You can see the following examples for these:
***renderField*** - http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/unsupported-iframe-urls-in-sitecore-page-editor-mode/ (Sample of HtmlUtility is also present here - instead of selecting all  tags, you could select all  and add your desired class attribute.)

***saveRichTextContent*** - http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/06/14/wrapping-rich-text-value-in-paragraph-tag-in-sitecore/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to just add the Class to the Rich Text Editor for use in the Editor.

There are lots of good articles on doing this.  Here are a couple:
http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.com/2013/11/add-css-class-to-richtext-editor.html
http://markstiles.net/Blog/2011/08/13/add-css-classes-to-sitecore-rich-text-editor.aspx

These are minimal changes that provide you with the ability to put the styling ability in the hands of the Content Author, but still controlling what styles and classes they can use inline.