# sitecore wrapping for tags pipeline in fields are not working

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, pipeline, pipelining, page-editor

I am using sitecore 7.2 & I have created pipeline for enclosing tags for single-line Text as below.

```
public class SingleLineFieldEnclosingTags
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            if (args.FieldTypeKey != "single-line text" && args.FieldTypeKey != "multi-line text")
                return;

            args.Result.FirstPart = Helper.WrapInTags(args);            
        }
    }

public static string WrapInTags(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            string keyInParam = args.Parameters.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("enclosingTag")).FirstOrDefault().Key;
            string wrappedText = args.Result.FirstPart;

            if (IsPageEditorMode)
            {
                return wrappedText;
            }

            if (keyInParam != null && keyInParam.Trim().Equals("enclosingTag"))
            {
                if (args.Parameters.ContainsKey(keyInParam))
                {
                    string[] paramTags = args.Parameters[keyInParam].Split('|').Reverse().ToArray();

                    foreach (string tag in paramTags)
                    {
                        wrappedText = string.Concat("<", tag.Trim(), ">", wrappedText, "</", tag.Trim().Split(' ')[0], ">");
                    }

                    if (wrappedText.Contains("enclosingTag"))
                    {                            
                        // remove enclosing tag attribute from tags
                        wrappedText = Regex.Replace(wrappedText, @"enclosingTag\s*=\""\s*?.*\""", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    }
                    return wrappedText;
                }
            }
            return wrappedText;
        }
```

It is working fine, but problem comes when we edit or save any field then it save it as

```
<p class="intro">Do you need something specific?</p>
```

including enclosing tags too. and now in publish mode it display twice, thrice and so one like below.

```
<p class="intro"></p>
<p class="intro"></p>
<p class="intro"></p>
<p class="intro">Do you need something specific?</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have added this pipeline to `Item:Saved`. As you have found, publishing actually also creates/saves the item in the web database, the same event is fired on that server and hence the reason you are seeing the repeated tags. Add a check to make sure you are running in the master database in your `process` method:

```
public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
{
    if (!args.Item.Database.Name.Equals("master", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        return;

    if (args.FieldTypeKey != "single-line text" && args.FieldTypeKey != "multi-line text")
        return;

    args.Result.FirstPart = Helper.WrapInTags(args);            
}
```

However, you may want to check if your text is already wrapped in the tag you are enclosing in (as well) - use [HTMLAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) instead of [messing with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/661447). In a simple scenario such as a `single-line text` field you could probably just get away with a `StartsWith()` check instead.

You should consider moving your code to the `renderField` pipeline instead (more info in this [blog post](https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecorebetter/posts/2013/06/extending-the-sitecore-renderfield-pipeline.aspx) or [this one](http://www.mikkelhm.dk/blog/ensuring-that-p-tag)), or make use of the `EnclosingTag` attribute of the `FieldRenderer`. This way the tags are added at render time, rather than appearing in the content editor. There is some code in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732912/add-enclosing-tag-for-only-unordered-list-from-rich-text-editor-in-ul/24735554#24735554) I posted previously that you can use to pass the css class as well.

Comment: BTW, should the `FieldTypeKey` check not be an OR (`||`) check?